# Is it possible to attach a case notification email reply to the case as a case comment?

Tags: email, email2case

Is it possible to have users' email replies to case notifications attached to that case as a case comment? I've looked pretty much everywhere, and even asked Salesforce support but no luck, they just say you need custom coding but don't say where to start. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Assuming you can forward a mailbox, you can do this with very little code.

1. Enable Email-to-Case (On-Demand) with a Routing Addresses if you haven't already,
2. Setup > Customize > Cases > Email Messages > Triggers,
3. Create a new trigger; here's an example to get you started:

   ```
   trigger InboundCaseComment on EmailMessage (before insert) {
     List<CaseComment> comments = new List<CaseComment>();
     for (EmailMessage message : trigger.new) {
       comments.add(new CaseComment(
         IsPublished = true,
         ParentId    = message.ParentId,
         CommentBody = message.FromName + '\n' + message.TextBody
       ));
     }
     INSERT comments;
   }
   ```

Just be aware, you may need to tweak your configuration to avoid dual notifications now :-)

**Edit:** just did a sanity check per your comment... mine catches incoming replies ok:
[image: response case comment]

So when the case owner sends emails, they're *"from"* the routing address which has a dedicated mailbox, eg `support@example.com`). The customer responds *to* the same. Your mail system must *forward* that mailbox to something like `derp@q-12345.d-abcde.dl.case.salesforce.com`

[image: routing addresses]

Reconfirming with the screenshot below, the nice short Email-to-Case address needs to be selected (*From*) when sending emails. Hopefully this addresses your comment about the users' send-to address.

[image: from email-to-case address]

From an engineering point of view, this whole function is pretty bang-bang out of the box. I'm surprised Salesforce don't crow about it more.

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried it, and it does add the initial notification email to the case but the the incoming replies. thoughts?

Comment: can you triple-confirm for me that you have On-Demand Email-to-Case configured?

Comment: Yes I did confirm that my Email on demand is set up, and i put the routing address as my own email. I used the exact same code and generated a notification and replied to it. It just went to my email and not added to the case. don't know what's going on. :-(

Comment: You are so close! You need to grab the ugly long email off the Routing Addresses table in Email-to-Case setup and send the reply to _that one_. In real use, you'd use the forwarder per the setup guide.

Comment: oooh.. I know, i am so close i can almost taste it! I see what you mean now! i replied to that ugly email service address and it attached!! Now i just need to figure out how to make that appear in users' "Send To" field in Outlook!

Comment: do you know i can find the documentation for setting up this forwarder? I couldn't find it.

Comment: If your mail runs on MS Exchange / Outlook, that's probably one for your company's network admin. They may need to create the dedicated `support@yourcompany.com` mailbox, then an 'inbox rule' to forward all mail to `support@q-123...salesforce.com`. You may need a pointed stick.

Comment: Ok. Awesome. Thank you so much for the help! Really appreciate it! :-)

Comment: @user320, is there a way to copy only the reply, and not the original email? the part "On Wed, Feb 6 2013...." in your example, is pretty redundant as a comment...

Answer (score 1):

You would need to develop  code around the EmailMessage object.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm

Basically, the idea would be a trigger that takes the reply ("BODY"), and copies that into the parent case comment.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks ok but do one thing -

Setup your email mail box email forwarding setting.

Set email as : email-to-case routing address

It helps when customer reply on this mail. 
It will automatically add case comment to this particular case

Comment: Hi Amit. For your answer to be well rated please allow me to suggest: proper punctuation (periods at the end of sentences), proper case (capital letters at the beginning of sentences), screen shots of what you are suggesting, removing the signature line. This last one may seem odd if you've used other forums, but is accepted practice in Stackexchange.

Comment: Hi Peter. thanks for your kind suggestion. actually my English is not so good.

Comment: Your english is fine. Being bilingual I know it can be daunting to wade into a dicussion in a foreign language, but you only improve in a language by using that language (either spoken or programming), so good on you for giving it a go. :-)